# Convert XML Dom Structure while deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have to transform the XML DOM structure into another XML DOM structure, How can I perform it using custom serialization implemented via IXmlSerialization. The source and target XML structure are mentioned as below

### Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigFileRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<DeviceConnectionParams>
    <DeviceConnectionParam>
      <UserId>administrator</UserId>
      <Password>B670AAB84F449BF3953C5ABE947DEF0C</Password>      
      <IsManual>True</IsManual>
    </DeviceConnectionParam>
</DeviceConnectionParams>   
<AlarmMappings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <AlarmA>
        <Events>
            <EventId>
                <PanelId>1</PanelId>
                <PanelName>TestAccess</PanelName>
                <DeviceId>65</DeviceId>
                <DeviceName>TestPanel</DeviceName>            
            </EventId>
            <EventId>
                <PanelId>1</PanelId>
                <PanelName>TestAccess</PanelName>
                <DeviceId>65</DeviceId>
                <DeviceName>TestPanel</DeviceName>            
            </EventId>
        </Events>
    </AlarmA>
     <AlarmB>
        <AlarmId>0a103f2b3ce7498c4fcaafb965c742cca66a221027054490eab5459689303bbea1f81898380c</AlarmId>
        <NvrUuid>0a1027054490eab5459689303bbea1f818983801</NvrUuid>
      </AlarmB>
</AlarmMappings>    
</ConfigFileRoot>
```

### Target XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigFileRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<DeviceConnectionParams>
    <DeviceConnectionParam>
      <UserId>administrator</UserId>
      <Password>B670AAB84F449BF3953C5ABE947DEF0C</Password>      
      <IsManual>True</IsManual>
    </DeviceConnectionParam>
</DeviceConnectionParams>   
<AlarmMappings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <AlarmA>
        <Events>
            <EventId>
                <PanelId>1</PanelId>
                <PanelName>TestAccess</PanelName>
                <DeviceId>65</DeviceId>
                <DeviceName>TestPanel</DeviceName>            
            </EventId>              
        </Events>
    </AlarmA>
     <AlarmB>           <AlarmId>0a103f2b3ce7498c4fcaafb965c742cca66a221027054490eab5459689303bbea1f81898380c</AlarmId>
        <NvrUuid>0a1027054490eab5459689303bbea1f818983801</NvrUuid>
      </AlarmB>
</AlarmMappings>
<AlarmMappings>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <AlarmA>
        <Events>                
            <EventId>
                <PanelId>1</PanelId>
                <PanelName>TestAccess</PanelName>
                <DeviceId>65</DeviceId>
                <DeviceName>TestPanel</DeviceName>            
            </EventId>
        </Events>
    </AlarmA>
     <AlarmB>
        <AlarmId>0a103f2b3ce7498c4fcaafb965c742cca66a221027054490eab5459689303bbea1f81898380c</AlarmId>
        <NvrUuid>0a1027054490eab5459689303bbea1f818983801</NvrUuid>
      </AlarmB>
</AlarmMappings>    
</ConfigFileRoot>
```

Comment: On first glance, this looks a lot like you've done no research and are just asking for a solution to your problem. Perhaps read [ask], and when you've researched and attempted to solve the problem yourself ask a *specific* question if you get stuck.

Comment: I have implemented the "IXmlSerializable" interface and can easily read the XML in form of source XML, but couldn't find any way to transform the structure in memory. I can easily implement the writeXML for the required output, but how to change the structure via readxml method is still a puzzle to me. Any pointer for this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In which case, it's not entirely clear from the question what it is you're actually struggling with. It would be helpful to add some code; a [mcve] that shows a much smaller example than the full XML that would help us to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I got the fix and it start working. In "ReadXML" i have populated a temp object and updated the mapping after completion.